# Should I put colons with second-level titles?

Tags: titles, punctuation

I'm writing a documentation for an eGovernment project, so the document I'm writing is a scientific document. It contains some big ideas, each having some subideas, with each subidea having a number of paragraphs.

The question is that at the title of each subidea (wich contains only paragraphs, no free text), should I put colons?

The paragraphs contain explanations sometimes, so should I put colons for the paragraphs' titles?

This is an example:

> ## Motivating People
>
> ### Reputation System
>
> #### Needs for
>   reputation system
>
> It's needed due to several reasons (so
>   mentioning the reasons).
>
> #### Mechanism
>
> The system works as
>   follows: (so mentioning how it works).
>
> ### Trust System
>
> .......

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Is Heading-2 in relation to Microsoft Word?

Comment: I've edited the title, is it better now?

Comment: A *leetle* more context. What kind of document is this? Is there any text after the titles? Sometimes? After 2 but not 1?

Comment: Could you give a real example, with some context?  Does Title 2 immediately follow Title 1?  (In that case sometimes title *1* gets a colon, but not 2.)

Comment: Is it clear now? sorry for taking your time :(

Comment: No need to apologize.  Thanks; this is much clearer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you're writing for the government they might have a format they expect, so if so and it says something on this point, it wins.

Otherwise, I would not use colons in any of your titles or paragraphs.  The colon's job is to introduce what follows (e.g. in a list), but a title/subtitle/subsubtitle/etc structure already provides that implicitly.

The one case where I would use a colon in a title is in a document title that has a subtitle, e.g. "A History of the McGuffin: A Literature Survey".  But I would prefer to represent all of that as the title, not title + subtitle, so I would only do that if a style guide forced me to separate the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you do **not** need colons with your subheadings (the headings above your sub-ideas).